# Why RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.fr/$1 [L,R=301,NC] keeps old category in new url redirection?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I moved my wordpress blog to a new server. First I hosted my blog in a subfolder of my main website (www.main.fr/blog/).
Now I separated both websites and moved my blog to a subdomain (www.blog.main.fr).

Old URL of my blog : `www.main.fr/blog/`
New URL of my blog : `blog.main.fr`

In .htaccess of my old blog(www.main.fr/blog/, I try to redirect all pages from `www.main.fr/blog/[all-pages]` to `blog.new.fr/[all-pages]`.

The problem is that my new url rediction are : `blog.new.fr/blog/[all-pages]`.

I tried this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ https://blog.new.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but also :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^main.fr/blog [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.main.fr/blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://blog.new.fr/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

For exemple :
For an article like : `www.old.fr/blog/article1/`
I expect a redirection like : `www.blog.main.fr/article1/`
Instead I get : `www.blog.main/blog/article1/` (page not found)

Why my new urls keep the  `/blog/` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want "blogs" outside the capture in the regex.

```
RedirectMatch "^/blogs/(.*)" https://blog.new.fr/$1
```